# Difference between cloning methods?

Tags: star-wars

We know that cloning using Spaarti technology is a highly unstable method and only takes one year to mature, and that Kaminoan techniques were more stable but took about ten years to mature.

**What are the chief differences between these two methods?**

Comment: For starters, Spaarti cloning techniques solely exist within the (now non-canon) EU books and guidebooks so there's no canonical difference.

Comment: @Richard I am not really looking for a canonical answer, I am just curious as to what the difference is.

Comment: What are you wanting to know that isn't covered here; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Spaarti_cloning_cylinder and here http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kamino_cloning_chamber?

Comment: @Richard the wikia pages explain what each one of them methods do in general but never explain how the process of Spaarti cloning causes Clone Madness and why Kaminoan cloning doesn't.

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Clone_madness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Spaarti cloning** was a quick 1 year turn around in which the clone was given a 'flash' memory of basic skills and training.  - http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Spaarti_cloning_cylinder

**Kaminoan cloning** created a young clone whose maturity to adulthood was accelerated, but allowed for years of practical training in combat and other avenues. As a result the Kaminoan clones were vastly superior soldiers compared to the Spaarti soldiers. - http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kamino_cloning_chamber

Grand Admiral Thrawn discovered that with the force suppressing abilities of ysalamiri he could grow stable clones from Spaarti cylinders in a matter of 21 days. Also, instead of using a single clone template, he utilized the best soldiers, pilots, and commandos in the Empire to flash train his troops. Thereby enabling to get better clone units than by the old method.